# MySQL returning the wrong Date/Time

Tags: c#, mysql

I am receiving a date of 33/22/2014 12:00:00 AM when the date in the MySQL Database is 2014-03-22.  Can anyone tell me why it is returning a weird date? I am assuming it has to do with the `Convert Zero Datetime`.. but I am not entirely sure.

Code:

```
public MySqlDataReader readerDB(string strSelectStmnt)
{
    //initializing command
    var comm = new MySqlCommand(strSelectStmnt, conn);

    //datareader for reading values from table
    dr = comm.ExecuteReader();

    //return the information from that was gathered by the datareader
    return dr;
}

while (dr.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(0)));
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(1)));
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(2)));
}
```

**My Connection String**:

```
string MyConString = "Server=" + strIP + ";" +
                     "PORT=" + strPort + ";" +
                     "DATABASE=" + strDB + ";" +
                     "Persist Security Info=no;" +
                     "Convert Zero Datetime=True;" +
                     "username=" + strDBUID + ";" +
                     "password=" + strDBPWD + ";";
```

**My Query**:

```
var dr = db.readerDB("SELECT `trial_1_end` , `trial_2_end` , `permanent_end` FROM " +
                      DataTable + " WHERE item_name= '"+ strTmpSubscription +
                      "' AND username='" + User + "'AND password='" + Password + "'");
```

**My Results** (from a `Console.WriteLine`):

31/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
31/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
33/22/2014 12:00:00 AM

**ANSWER:**

```
    DateTime.ParseExact(dr.GetDateTime(0).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "dd/MM/yyyy", null)
```

Comment: show how you're sucking those dates into c#, because mysql itself would not mangle dates like that.

Comment: What is so weird about a date im ISO Format? On top, C# will format the datte in the culture of the thread that is actually turning the DateTIme into a- string. Basic C#.

Comment: TomTom - the arrangement of the date time structure is fine.  The fact it is giving me 33 as a month is the issue.

Marc - I edited for more clarity.

Comment: Prix - dr.GetDateTime(x) returned the same value. The column is of DateTime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can use the `SqlDataReader` method `GetDateTime`:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Console.WriteLine(dr.GetDateTime(0).ToString());
```

[And you can as well give it your custom formatting like:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Console.WriteLine(dr.GetDateTime(0).ToString("dd/MM/yy H:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The problem was with my code.  Thank you.

Comment: @JonH. `.ToString` have less overhead and you can easily customize the output, beyond that your date field is either wrong or have incorrect input.